# Add two spans with classes into a WP Menu's li

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation

I need to add two spans into the `<li></li>` of a WordPress menu. One contains the elements page title and one contains the description. 
I've found out how to add one span into the li, but not how to create two.
Any help?

Basic mark-up:

```
    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-left">
        <li>
            <a href="">
                <span class="dropdown-menu-pagetitle">Test Title</span>
                <span class="dropdown-menu-pagedescr">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteteur adipiscing</span>
            </a>
        </li>
[.......]
```

EDIT:

```
    class My_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth)
    {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown-menu pull-left\">\n";
    }

    function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array())
    {
        $output .= $item->label . '<span class="dropdown-menu-pagedescr">' . $item->description . '</span>';
    } 
}
```

My current nav:

```
        <?php 

$menu_args = array(
    'container'       => false, 
    'menu_class'      => 'nav nav-pills pull-right', 
    'menu_id'         => 'Navigation',
    'link_before'     => '<span class="dropdown-menu-pagetitle">',
    'link_after'      => '</span>',
    'walker' => new My_Walker_Nav_Menu()
    );

wp_nav_menu($menu_args ); 

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a custom Walker to achieve this. This is basically a class that is used by the Wordpress as instructions on how to build a menu.

There is lots of documentation out there on how to create walkers, but I find practice is the best way to learn how to use them.

I would recommend you use the `start_el()` function so the description is added before any submenu items. The following articles should help get you started:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker
- http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/understanding-the-walker-class/
- http://www.kriesi.at/archives/improve-your-wordpress-navigation-menu-output

**UPDATE:**

Someone has asked a very similar question on the Wordpress Stack Exchange site:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14037/menu-items-description-custom-walker-for-wp-nav-menu/14039#14039

That is probably the best place to start!

Comment: Did it! Thank you! However, my Walker is always outside of the anchor tag :/

Comment: Ok, well if you add your Walker code and some sample output to your question I might possibly be able to help.

Comment: Ok, try using `start_el()` instead of `end_el()`. The link is built within the start_el function so you must edit that function if you want to add the description inside the same link as the title.